# get file content of google docs using google drive API v3

Tags: google-drive-api

Is there any way to get the content of native files (Google Docs) using Google Drive API v3? I know API v2 supports this with the exportLinks property, but it doesn't work anymore or has been removed.

Comment: although some of the answers works for getting the last version of a native google doc, I couldn't find export for revisions of a native google doc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For v3 of the api, you can use the export method https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/export

Comment: although it works for getting the last version, I couldn't find export for revisions of a native google doc

Answer (score 21):

You can also download files with binary content (non google drive file) in Drive using the `webContentLink` attribute of a file. From https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files:

> A link for downloading the content of the file in a browser. This is
> only available for files with binary content in Drive.

An example (I use method [`get()`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get) to retrieve the `webContentLink` from my file):

```
gapi.client.drive.files.get({
    fileId: id,
    fields: 'webContentLink'
}).then(function(success){
    var webContentLink = success.result.webContentLink; //the link is in the success.result object
    //success.result    
}, function(fail){
    console.log(fail);
    console.log('Error '+ fail.result.error.message);
})
```

---

With google drive files, the export method can be used to get those files: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/export
This method needs an object with 2 mandatory attributes (`fileId`, and `mimeType`) as parameters.
A list of available `mimeType`s can be seen [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/mime-types) or [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-export-formats) (thanks to @ravioli)

Example:

```
gapi.client.drive.files.export({
    'fileId' : id,
    'mimeType' : 'text/plain'
}).then(function(success){
    console.log(success);
    //success.result    
}, function(fail){
    console.log(fail);
    console.log('Error '+ fail.result.error.message);
})
```

---

You can read non google doc file content (for example a text file) with `gapi.client.drive.files.get` with `alt:"media"`. [Official example](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads). My example:

```
function readFile(fileId, callback) {
    var request = gapi.client.drive.files.get({
        fileId: fileId,
        alt: 'media'
    })
    request.then(function(response) {
        console.log(response); //response.body contains the string value of the file
        if (typeof callback === "function") callback(response.body);
    }, function(error) {
        console.error(error)
    })
    return request;
}
```

Comment: Nice and clean explanation. You saved my day, Phu!

Comment: @phuwin I'm trying to dowload a plain text file from drive and the first solution you provided fails because of CORS when I try to `GET` the `webContentLink`. The third option returns the contents in a raw string containing the file contents and some additional info wrapped inside a `WebkitFormBoundary` which I'm not sure how to parse properly. I should mention that my app is purely client-side browser app.

Comment: @MarošBeťko I'm afraid I have no clue to answer your question. You might need to add a new question in a different stackoverflow post with more information about your situation. Or you can check `@noogui` answer.

Comment: @phuwin Here is the related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57240830/google-drive-api-download-file-within-drive-appdata-scope

Comment: Updated link for export mime types: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-export-formats

Answer (score 6):

If you use [files.export](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/export#try-it), you won't get any link that will let you download the file as stated in [v3 Migration guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration).

For example using the the try-it, I only got a MiMetype response but no downloadable link:

```
[application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text data]
```

Workaround for this is a direct download. Just replace `FILE_ID` with your Google Doc fileID and execute it in the browser. Through this, I was able to export Google docs files.

```
https://docs.google.com/document/d/FILE_ID/export?format=doc
```

Credits to [labnol's guide](http://www.labnol.org/internet/direct-links-for-google-drive/28356/) for the workaround.