# How to solve Google.Apis.Download.DownloadStatus.Failed situation while downloading file from google drive

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I have obtained the client_secret.json and installed **google apis** as well as **OAUTH2** libraries for **C#**. I am **able to list, create or delete files and folders** in my drive. But **Download fails**.

I have tried a couple of methods.
1. Downloading file using Files.Export
2. Downloading file using WebRequest

In first method, i am getting **Google.Apis.Download.DownloadStatus.Failed** status, and file is not downloading.

In second method, everything goes through and an invalid file of 73KB is getting generated on given path. But *I would prefer discussing that in another thread.*

```
/* some params for getting Credentials */

private static string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.Drive, DriveService.Scope.DriveFile,DriveService.Scope.DriveAppdata,DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly};
private static string ApplicationName = "DM2";
private static string credPath = "E:\\token.json";
private static String secretPath = "E:\\client_secret.json";

/* method to download file using Files.Export */

public static string DownloadFile(string fId,string destFolder)
        {
            var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            try
            {
                Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File f = GoogleDriveAccessor.GetFile(fId);                
                if (f.MimeType != "application/vnd.google-apps.folder")
                {
                    DriveService ds = GetService();
                    FilesResource.ExportRequest eReq = ds.Files.Export(fId, f.MimeType);                   
                    String retPath = "";
                    bool opComp = false;

                    eReq.MediaDownloader.ProgressChanged += 
                        (IDownloadProgress progress) =>
                        {
                            switch (progress.Status)
                            {

                                case DownloadStatus.Downloading:
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine(progress.BytesDownloaded);
                                        opComp = false;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                case DownloadStatus.Completed:
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine("Download complete.");
                                        opComp = true;
                                        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(destFolder + "/" + f.Name, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                                        {
                                            stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                                            retPath = fileStream.Name;
                                            fileStream.Dispose();                                            
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    }
                                case DownloadStatus.Failed:
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine("Download failed.");
                                        opComp = true;
                                        break;
                                    }
                            }
                        };

                    eReq.Download(stream);                    
                    return retPath;                    
                }
                return null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                stream.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

This is always leading me to DownloadStatus.Failed , whereas I am expecting the method to download the file. 
I am disposing the stream in finally block so that its not destroyed before the operation completes.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code i use personally its a bit different from yours.

```
private static void DownloadFile(Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService service, Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File file, string saveTo)
        {

            var request = service.Files.Get(file.Id);
            var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

            // Add a handler which will be notified on progress changes.
            // It will notify on each chunk download and when the
            // download is completed or failed.
            request.MediaDownloader.ProgressChanged += (Google.Apis.Download.IDownloadProgress progress) =>
               {
                   switch (progress.Status)
                   {
                       case Google.Apis.Download.DownloadStatus.Downloading:
                           {
                               Console.WriteLine(progress.BytesDownloaded);
                               break;
                           }
                       case Google.Apis.Download.DownloadStatus.Completed:
                           {
                               Console.WriteLine("Download complete.");
                               SaveStream(stream, saveTo);
                               break;
                           }
                       case Google.Apis.Download.DownloadStatus.Failed:
                           {
                               Console.WriteLine("Download failed.");
                               break;
                           }
                   }
               };
            request.Download(stream);

        }


private static void SaveStream(System.IO.MemoryStream stream, string saveTo)
{
     using (System.IO.FileStream file = new System.IO.FileStream(saveTo, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
        {
         stream.WriteTo(file);
         }
}
```

Code ripped from [download files from Google drive](https://www.daimto.com/download-files-from-google-drive-with-c/)

Comment: Hi, the codes are almost similar. SaveStream method as per your code, will get called if DownloadStatus is **Completed** . In my case, upon calling request.Download(stream), ** i get DownloadStatus as Failed. ** Thats the basic problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had recently encountered this error and found a solution.
I got this error because I was using a `FilesResource.GetRequest` instead of a `FilesResource.ExportRequest` object when trying to download an xlsx from Google drive. This has to do with the object being [binary vs non binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39381563/get-file-content-of-google-docs-using-google-drive-api-v3/39408884). I was downloading a binary file (non-Google object). You're trying to download a Google object (a folder), so try using a GetRequest instead of an ExportRequest. Example of [my working code here](https://github.com/christian-xa/Drive-API-Download-File-C).

Hope this helps. Let me know if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

First, use

```
request.DownloadWithStatus(stream);
```

Second, create memory stream as disposable

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
   // Your code here
}
```

Most likely reason for failure is downloading multiple large files and running out of memory