# How can I show the content of a text file with Google Drive Api v3 and php?

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I want show the content of a text file stored in a folder on Google Drive.
I'm using the Google Drive Api v3.
At moment I'm able to show only filename and MimeType but that I need is the content. I want the text file text as string
I can't find a suitable function.

This is part of my code so far

```
function getClient()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Google Drive API PHP Quickstart');
    $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
    $client->setDeveloperKey('$myApiKey'); // API key

    // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    // time.
    $tokenPath = 'token.json';
    if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    }

    // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        } else {
            // Request authorization from the user.
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
            print 'Enter verification code: ';
            $authCode = $myAuthCode;

            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

            // Check to see if there was an error.
            if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
            }
        }
        // Save the token to a file.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client;
}


// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
    $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

[...]

        $file = $service->files->get($fileId); 
    print "Title: " . $file->getName();
    print "Description: " . $file->getDescription();
    print "MIME type: " . $file->getMimeType();
```

Can you help me?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39381563/get-file-content-of-google-docs-using-google-drive-api-v3) answer might help

Comment: I don't know how to use it, could you give me an example?

Comment: Following the link in @jibsteroos's comment will eventually lead you [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export), to the file export method.

Comment: @furman87 But ... the export method does download the file with another mimetype, I instead want to have the text of the content as a string so I can work on it in PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the file content from Google Drive using Drive API.

  - The file is the text file which is not Google Docs (Google Document, Spreadsheet, Slides and so on).
- You want to achieve this using google-api-php-client with php.
- You have already been able to get values from Google Drive using Drive API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please use `alt=media` for downloading the file.

#### Modified script:

```
$file = $service->files->get($fileId); 
print "Title: " . $file->getName();
print "Description: " . $file->getDescription();
print "MIME type: " . $file->getMimeType();

$content = $service->files->get($fileId, array("alt" => "media"));  // Added
print $content->getBody();  // Added
```

- `$service->files->get($fileId)` downloads the file metadata. So in order to download the file content, please use `$service->files->get($fileId, array("alt" => "media"))`.

#### References:

- [Download files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads)
- [google-api-php-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

### Added:

#### Pattern 1:

When you want to use the access token retrieved by OAuth2, please use the following script. In this case, the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` is used. When you run the script, the URL for retrieving the authorization code is shown in the console. So please put it to your browser and authorize the scope. And input the code of the browser to the console. By this, the access token and refresh token are retrieved and the script works.

Sample script:

```
function getClient()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Google Drive API PHP Quickstart');
    $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_READONLY);
    $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

    // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    // time.
    $tokenPath = 'token2.json';
    if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    }

    // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        } else {
            // Request authorization from the user.
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
            print 'Enter verification code: ';
            $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

            // Check to see if there was an error.
            if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
            }
        }
        // Save the token to a file.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client;
}

$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

$fileId = "###";  // Please set the file ID of the text file on Google Drive.

// Retrieve file metadata.
$file = $service->files->get($fileId);
print "Title: " . $file->getName();
print "Description: " . $file->getDescription();
print "MIME type: " . $file->getMimeType();

// Download file.
$content = $service->files->get($fileId, array("alt" => "media"));
file_put_contents("sample.txt", $content->getBody()); // Please set the filename you want.
```

- When you run this script, the file is downloaded and save it as a file.

#### Pattern 2:

When you want to use the API key, please use the following script. In this case, the file is required to be publicly shared. Please be careful this.

Sample script:

```
function getClient()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Google Drive API PHP Quickstart');
    $client->setDeveloperKey('###');  // Please set your API key.
    return $client;
}

$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

$fileId = "###";  // Please set the file ID of the text file on Google Drive.

// Retrieve file metadata.
$file = $service->files->get($fileId);
print "Title: " . $file->getName();
print "Description: " . $file->getDescription();
print "MIME type: " . $file->getMimeType();

// Download file.
$content = $service->files->get($fileId, array("alt" => "media"));
file_put_contents("sample.txt", $content->getBody()); // Please set the filename you want.
```

- When you run this script, the file is downloaded and save it as a file.

Comment: Yes I think you understand correctly, but for more specific clarity that what I need is the text in the text file as a string. I tried your suggestion but it brings me this error:
Fatal error: Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "appNotAuthorizedToFile", "message": "The user has not granted the app *** read access to the file ***.", "locationType": "header", "location": "Authorization" } ], "code": 403, "message": "The user has not granted the app *** read access to the file ***" }... 

I edit my post with my connection setting.

Comment: @Vincenzo Auriemma Thank you for your replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your replying and your added script, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? Unfortunately, from your additional script, I couldn't understand which you want to use the access token or API key. I apologize for this. So I added 2 patterns. And for both patterns, the file is downloaded and save it as a file. If I misunderstood your goal, I apologize.

Comment: Now I have set as in pattern 1 but the problem remains (I tried them both but nothing changes).
I want to insist that I don't want to download the file as a file, but I want the text contained in the text file as a string to be able to work on it with PHP.

Comment: @Vincenzo Auriemma Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `I want the text contained in the text file as a string`, my 1st sample script can achieve this. How about it? If my 1st sample script is not the result you want, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. At that time, can I ask you about the detail information of your goal? I would like to confirm it. By the way, `the problem remains` is this?

Comment: In truth I have to thank you for the support. Even my English is not the best so sorry for possible misunderstandings.

I was just using your first code and the settings of pattern1 and until yesterday evening it was giving the error indicated above ... now, without having touched anything, it works perfectly. So yes you have achieved my goal. Thank you

Comment: @Vincenzo Auriemma Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.